# What if to load duplicated blocks e.g. header and footer by JS

Tags: seo, google-search, html, search-engines, static-content

If we use static site generators (SSG) and edit some block duplicated on many pages e.g. header or footer, we need to regenerate all the HTML pages using this block. Regardless of the speed of our SSG, the process takes a time. And the more pages we have, the more time we need to wait.

But what if we store the code of duplicated block e.g. header or footer only in one place and load their HTML codes to the pages on the fly by JavaScript?

I mean if the source code of HTML page just has unchanged `<head>` with link(s) to CSS and `<body>` with unique main content for the page like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

  <header></header>
  <script>
  var headerReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  headerReq.open('GET', 'header.html', false);
  headerReq.send();
  document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].innerHTML = headerReq.responseText;
  </script>

  <article>
  <h1>Page Heading</h1>
  <p>
  Main content
  </p>
  </article>

  <footer></footer>
  <script>
  var footerReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
  footerReq.open('GET', 'footer.html', false);
  footerReq.send();
  document.getElementsByTagName('footer')[0].innerHTML = footerReq.responseText;
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And we load header and footer (as well as other blocks duplicated on many pages) to the DOM by our JS as codes before and after the main content.

If we change the main content, we may only regenerate the single post page with the content and the category page containing the intro text of the post i.e. regenerate just two HTML pages.

And if we change header or footer, there is no need to regenerate HTML pages at all. We just change such block in one place and JS refreshes it on all the pages when we open any of them.

But will there be the issue of mismatching the source code (we see after right-click and "View page source") and the final DOM code (we see after right-click and "Inspect Element")? The issue described by the link https://www.polemicdigital.com/view-source-quickly-compare-raw-html-rendered-dom

To avoid the issue in our JS we can check user agent and load the header and the footer only for users and not for the bots.

What are the downside(s) of the approach?

ps. I know, in such case if we inline critical CSS and later want to change it, we still need to regenerate all the pages with such critical CSS. And with HTTP/2 there is probably no need in critical CSS at all.

---

**UPDATED**

**The main question is**: to load duplicated parts for both users and search bots OR only for users?

If we load for both, there are at least two issues: 1) the SEO issue of mismatching the source code and the final DOM code and 2) the SEO issue of a delay as search bots need more time to render and index a page with code loaded by JS than a page with only normal source code.

If we load duplicated parts only for users and NOT for the bots, there may be the issue of cloaking or/and hidden texts. *However, I can't understand why as the bots don't see the duplicated parts and can't compare the code they get with the code users get.

Comment: How many pages are on your site?   I used a static site generator for a site until it grew to about 30,000 pages at which point that got unwieldy.    But for me even tens of thousands of pages only took 5 minutes to generate.

Comment: It's not about a specific website, it's a general question

Answer (score 1):

> will there be the issue of mismatching the source code

I think, for sure. Before rendering there will be just a javascript, after rendering there will be javascript + new content, pulled by javascript. But this shouldn't cause any negative effect.

> and JS refreshes it on all the pages when we open any of them

I suspect here some cache issues - not critical, but think about it.

> render-blocking issue

If you don't block javascript by robots, there shouldn't be any.

In general, this is not a kind of new or special approach. It isn't critical for indexing too. You should just think about some things in advance and there will be nothing critical. I.e. Googlebot is waiting about 6 seconds after `onLoad` for arriving of new content. Make sure, your javascript is fast enough and you are safe.

Comment: As I mentioned, I would like to load header and footer by JS only for live users and not for the bots. So the bots will not see header and footer at all. I don't see a reason to index them as they don't have valuable contents. The home page may have header including nav menu with links to inner pages and footer in its source code. But if we create inner pages, they just have its main contents. And if we open any of them, JS gets the header and the footer from the `index.html` and load them to the DOM of the inner page. As I can understand, it also resolves the cache issues(?).

Comment: `and not for the bots` - doing so you are at risc to be penalized for cloacking. How do you want to decide, who is the bot, and who is a human? Deciding on user agent and delivering different content is against Google's ToS. Don't risc it - deliver everything for all, but use for non-meaningful parts a kind of lazy loading.

Comment: As I know, it's normal to prevent a piece of code be indexed by search engines. The cloaking is _"presenting different content... to human users and search engines"_. But we're talking not about _content_, but about _header_ and _footer_. And what do you mean under the _lazy loading_?

Comment: `to prevent a piece of code be indexed by search engines` - afaik there is no legit technics to do so, beside of loading or not loading, depending on user agent. What you name `header+footer` is for bots content. Whether it is chrome, is a decision, done by heuristics after crawling. But ok, lets suppose, we deliver different chrome for different mobile agents - then it is ok to deliver different page versions. With `lazy loading` i mean a kind of defering, i.e. you load footer only if user scrolls down to the end of page.

Comment: `there is no legit technics to do so` by the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685205/noindex-tag-for-google) there is a mention about iframe and other references. Do you mean Google views such non-crawlable parts of page including iframes as hidden texts and/or cloaking?

Comment: oh-oh, iframes... yes, you are right - iframe, and then close the source with robots or noindex, it could work... But... do you `really` need such  heavy stuff? I mean, it makes efforts, but if i imagine header and footer as iframes, i feel a bit seek :) I mean, if a bot sees iframes on places where it expects some kind of navigational stuff it `could` become fishy

Comment: Iframe was just an example. But actually I found a better way — SSI. It adds duplicated part in source code and works very fast. The only thing I can't understand yet is security. There is a mention about SSI injections and I don't know which is safer: SSI or Ajax (XMLHttpRequest/Fetch API) I mentioned in my question